# how do i create a Funnel chart in angular app already using ngx charts for other charts in our project

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I need to render this kinda chart[Requiremnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDwMW.png)

I have tried using horizontal bar charts in ngx charts but didnt get expected results. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this using ngx-charts